# Creating a User-less Distro

Tags: ubuntu, users, opensuse, distributions

One of the popular programs I use is GParted, and it has its own custom distro, that boots straight to the desktop, and starts the program. I couldn't find any information on creating such a distro. I need it to be where I can install packages of my choosing, just without the user system. Is this possible to remove from a base installation of openSUSE or Ubuntu?

Comment: The Ubuntu Live CD / installer image also does this. Perhaps that's actually all you really need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you'd like to just automatically boot straight into a system without having to login? That's essentially what they're doing in GParted. You are a user if you go to the terminal and type the command `whoami`, you are an actual user.

#### example

[image: ss of user]

You can do this with pretty much any distro. All that's required is to set it up so that it automatically logs in instead of asking you.

See this tutorial on ubuntu.com - [AutoLogin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoLogin)

As for elevating this auto logged in user's credentials, again this can be done by adding them to sudo so that they aren't challenged for their password.

See this askubunu question - [Execute sudo without Password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password). The gist of it is to add the following entry in your sudoer's file (`/etc/sudoers`):

```
$ sudo visudo
```

*At the bottom of that file add this line*

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/).

Arch Linux allows you to build your system from the first floor up. You start with nothing and install packages to your desire.

Take a look at the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) for installation instructions. You will want to setup your system to [login automatically](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Automatic_login_to_virtual_console). If you wish to use a desktop environment, you will have to disable its login manager. Read [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autostarting#Graphical) for instructions on autostarting a program.